# calling jsonresult in simple html site through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Can we call MVC jsonresult in any simple html project through jquery. I mean can we use MVC projects as api and consume all jsonresult method in html project.

[image]

I just want to call above jsonresult in any html page i know i have ti use jquery to serialize the data. but it will not come.

Comment: Your question is still not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to load a json result in any simple html project through jquery or javascript by using **AJAX** inside your js functions.

- Use `jQuery.getJSON()` inside your `$(document).ready(function(){ })` for loading json object while your html page gets loaded intially.
- Also refer
  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

You may check out [MVC Controllers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/aspnet-mvc-controller-overview) or [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for this. They would easily accept and return JSON. So you would be able to do an AJAX call (POST, PUT or DELETE) to the Controller / WebAPI to serialize data and another call (GET) to fetch data in JSON.